Expected input batch_size (511) to match target batch_size (0)
I get this error while trying to train the llm model ,where my mistake and what is needed to be changed.
this my code,
i'm trying running it in colab and have enough resources.
i;m biggenier in this field.

# Load dataset

dataset = load_dataset("emotion")
dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x: x["label"] is not None)  # Filter out examples with missing labels

Preprocess dataset
def preprocess_data(examples):
    # Tokenize the text
    inputs = tokenizer(
        examples["text"],  # Input texts
        max_length=512,     # Maximum length
        truncation=True,    # Truncate if longer than max_length
        padding="max_length"  # Pad to max_length
    )
    
    # **Ensure 'label' field exists and is formatted correctly**
    inputs["labels"] = inputs["input_ids"].copy()  # Initialize labels with input_ids
    
    # **Assuming the label field is indeed called 'label'**
    for i, label in enumerate(examples["label"]):
        inputs["labels"][i] = label
    

    return inputs
# torch.cuda.empty_cache()
tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(preprocess_data, batched=True)

# LoRA configuration
lora_config = LoraConfig(
    r=8,
    lora_alpha=16,
    target_modules=["q_proj", "v_proj"],
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)
model = get_peft_model(model, lora_config)

Training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./fine_tuned_llama_with_lora",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir="./logs",
    report_to="none"
)

# Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"].select(range(5000)),
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"].select(range(1500)),
)

# Train
trainer.train()


